# Ditty RSS ticker - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wysiwyg, arabic

I am using a plugin to show RSS feed on my website homepage. My website is bilingual (English and Arabic). The Feed ticker is working fine on the English Website on Desktop and Phone versions. But there is some issue on the Arabic Website only on the Phone version. The Arabic Text is overlapping on the ticker. I think it is relate to some CSS coding that I have used, but I cant figure it out. Screenshots attached for reference. Can anyone please look at the code below and help me with a possible solution? 
The code I am using in wysiwyg field;

```
 <div style="background: #5a267c; position: relative; border-right: none; 
 float: none; margin-left: auto; width: 100%; height: 85px;">
 <div class="container-fluid" style="background: #5a267c; max-width: 1200px;">
 <h4 style="float: right; color: white; padding-right: 70px; padding-top: 
 25px; padding-left: 10px;">
 آخر الأخبار
 </h4>
 <p style="padding-top: 25px;">[ditty_news_ticker id="5234"]</p>
 <p>
 <img class="rss-logo" style="position: absolute; height: 80px; bottom: 0; 
 padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;" src="http://www.alainc.msf.ae/wp- 
 content/themes/alainclub/images/headers/logo_center.png" alt="" /></p>
 </div></div>
```

CSS code that I am using for News Ticker;

```
 #rss_scr_spancontant a, .mtphr-dnt-rss-title a{
text-align:center;
font-weight:100;
color:white !important;
font-size:20px;
text-transform: none;
font-style: italic;
}
.mtphr-dnt-rss-title a:hover{
text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#banner-slide0` is changing height when screen size is reduced hence, you need to change this code in themes/alainclub/css/custom-ar.css

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
#banner-slide0 {
    height: 100px !Important;
}
```

to:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
#banner-slide0 {
    height: 140px !Important; /* Increase the height to fit your needs */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue was with the width of the banner-slide1 but the height was fine. I have set the banner according to screen height. Thank you @Hamza Ahmad for showing the right direction, I thought there was an issue with plugin CSS.